# Problem with pygame - failed loading libmeg123.dll

Tags: python, pygame

I have finished working on my app and there was no issues. Suddenly the next time when I turned on app without changing anything in the code I receive error:

```
testtempfile.py", line 50, in speak pygame.mixer.music.load(f)
pygame.error: Failed loading libmeg123.dll: Attempt to access invalid address
```

I haven't changed any settings, I have not updated pygame or python. I do not think that any new version of them has been released today. Any solution?

PS: I have tried to restart my IDE several times, same as rebooting PC. It did not worked

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found this here: [Edureka Solution](https://www.edureka.co/community/48166/python-pygame-failed-loading-libpng-dlopen-libpng-image-found).
If you run macOS, try `brew install libpng`

Comment: Unfortunately I am using Windows. There is libpng if I try to install it via pip

Answer (score 0):

I have found something really weird. When I installed PyQT5 with tools my app just stopped working correctly. Interesting thing is that if I will turn on QT Designer and my app everything works fantastic. If I will turn off QT Designer I get above error. I have no idea how these two are connected but I think this is worth mentioning so in case if anyone would have similar problem this person might have an idea what is wrong. I think I will just uninstall PyQT5 and tools in the meantime